Getting a nice upper bound for $\frac{r}{r+1-q}$ given that $\frac{1}{2}<q<p<r<1$?
Let $\frac{1}{2}<q<p<r<1$ (i.e., $q$, $p$ and $r$ are success rates of independent Bernoulli random variables). In the context of a model that I am constructing, I have arrived at the expression
$$\frac{r}{r+1-q}$$
and I want to compute some upper bound as a function of $p$. Put differently, I want to find some function of $p$, $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, such that
$$\frac{r}{r+1-q}<f(p),\forall q,p\text{ and } r$$
I suspect that the desired $f(p)$ is just $p$ and numerical computations appear to support this hypothesis but I am struggling to show this analytically. Any help will be much appreciated.

So you want to find $F_p = \max_{q, r} f( p, q, r) $. Show that this is maximized when $q\rightarrow 1, r \rightarrow p$, with the value of $ \frac{ 1}{ 2 - p } $.

@CalvinLin, why didn't I approach this as a maximization problem? Thanks and will edit the post to reflect your insight!

Please don't use "Edit: more stuff".  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Please don't edit your question to add an answer to your question.  Instead, write answers in the 'Your Answer' box, not in the question.

@D.W., Thank you, will do in the future.

It would be even better to revise this question now accordingly, rather than waiting for future questions.  This site is designed as a place where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge that will hopefully be helpful to others in the future.

The function $$\frac{r}{r+1-q}$$ is increasing in both $q$ and $r$ (fix one variable, and check the monotoncity for the other, just note $1-q>0$), so the upper bound $\frac{1}{2-p}$ is obtained by $q\to p^-$ and $r\to 1^-$.
